# Android Facebook-SDK

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

Hello I am trying to learn a little bit of facebook-sdk for android but no luck.

I will post some screenshots so you easy understand what is my problem.

1st step I am adding the SDk to my project
[image]

2nd step  I import Classes but i get an error
[image]

And when I am going back to android tab I see this
[image]

Really need help. I tried Many times to follow the steps from FB Guide in case I forgot something but didnt helped... Thank you in Advanced.(I am new to this hope you will understand)

Comment: I presume you do not delete the imported FacebookSDK project (step1) from Eclipse, or something like that?

Comment: No It is there I can see it.. But still getting errors.

Comment: Because according to step3 screen it looks like Eclipse cant find the sourcecode. Have you tried cleaning all the projects?

Comment: I was fallowing this Instructions: Yes I tried Cleaning
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/

Comment: I triedn now to copy the SDk into the workspace it worked but I get now this error Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies

Comment: The "Jar mismatch"-problem is because the different projects are based om differnet jar´s (typically Android suppor library). If that´s the case import the newest one into both projects; by right-click project -> Android Tools -> Add support Library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "Jar mismatch" problem comes into picture because of the Facebook SDK itself has android support v4 jar as well as your project also same jar file.

To solve this problem..

**Go to your project's properties -> Java Build Path -> Order and Export :
Now remove the Tick-Mark from Android Private Libraries.**

make sure that you had already used facebook SDK's private library (tick-marked)

And then after clean your work space..

It will always help me..
Hope this will help you to solve your problem.

Comment: I will try to do that, And will get back to you.